# Add object won't work in standalone BGE player with linked objects

Tags: game-engine, objects, linked-data

Here's my test scene setup:

[image]

Basically, the cone spawns objects every 30 frames. So, the sphere is located in another layer, it is present in the scene natively. Everything works fine in both embedded and standalone players. Everything work fine also with the object I **appended** to the scene.

[image]

The problem begins when I **link** an object from another scene. In this case it is *CubeBit2*. In embedded player it is perfectly fine.

[image]

But when I launch it in standalone player, - it spawns one **CubeBit2** at some random location and spawning with the cone doesn't work.

[image]

I tested it with another scene where there was a counter and differentiation between linked and native objects, so I'm positive it is not a problem with spawner cone.

Has anybody encountered this behaviour? Is there a way to make linked objects work with *Add Object* in standalone player? Maybe there is some option I'm missing that should be enabled to make linked objects work?